# Load UITableViewController programmatically and add view as subview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I want to load a UITableViewController inside a UIView because I want to change the view on button click (like UITabBar but with my own buttons). I'm using a storyboard and have defined a TableViewController with custom class "InitialTableViewController" and identifier "InitialView".

My code look like this:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "InitialTableViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    InitialTableViewController *tableControl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InitialView"];

    [[self view] addSubview:[tableControl view]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

@end
```

The view starts and I can see my table but the code inside "InitialTableViewController" doesn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: I think that you need to retain the `tableControl` instance somewhere. Have a property on `MyViewController` and set the value after you create it in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it would be easier to just have a normal `UIViewController` with a `UIView` as root of the Nib and then put a `UITableView`. My answer is based on your need to have buttons on that `UIView`.

Comment: Thx a lot. How can I add a navigation controller to use seque in my storyboard?

Comment: I found a solution by adding a UINavigationController in front of the UIViewController.